# How can I get MS office on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, wine, microsoft-office

I have office 2010, 2013 and 2016 and when I run it with wine I get an error when I click install. I'm new to Linux please help me

[image: The error]

Transcript of error:

> *User runs Office 2016 setup file (O16Setup.exe)*
>
> *Wine error message pops up with title `Program Error`.*
>
> The program setup.exe has encountered a serious problem and needs to close. 
>   We are sorry for the inconvenience.
>
> This can be caused by a problem in the program or a deficiency in Wine.
>   You may want to check the [Application Database](https://appdb.winehq.org/) for tips about running this application.

Comment: Can you give more details about the error messages and include them in your question?

Comment: Try whit this beta script: https://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-2665-Microsoft_Office_2013.html

Comment: i will put a picture,

Comment: I don't think 2016 is supported. The latest usable version is 2010, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PlayOnLinux can handle installation settings for you.

[Download install files from here](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/download.html) and install it.

When you run it, you can select "Install" and there is an option to install Office.  It will guide you to install Office using the executable setup file and take care of many settings for you that you would otherwise have to do manually with wine alone.

They also have an [extensive list of software](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/supported_apps.html) that shows what is compatible with POL, as well as some user workarounds for programs that have issues installing.

Comment: if you dont mind me asking, what is POL? im new to linux

Comment: @Adi Apologies!  POL is short for PlayOnLinux.  So when browsing sites and forums for PlayOnLinux you'll often see it referred to simply as POL.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot it works :) can you tell me how to get netbean's on here ?

Comment: No problem!  Well, if it's not in the install list in POL, you can click on "Install a non-listed program" in the bottom left of the Install menu where you found Office.  It'll try to install it as best it can.

Comment: I asked another question can you answer it for me please

Comment: @Adi  I answered your other question.  Take note in my other answer that there is a Linux version of NetBeans that you can install directly without fussing with POL.  I provided a link in my other answer.